# Why does scrapy fetch result in a bash syntax error?

Tags: scrapy, fetch

When I try fetch("http://quotes.toscrape.com/"), I receive the following error:

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `quotes.toscrape.com'

How can I fix this? Thanks for any advice!

I've tried removing the quotes and adding single quotes. I am using a Mac, and I'm not sure why it is adding the ` before the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the solution is to enter scrapy shell prior to calling fetch.